# set classes active to a route from another one with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue-router with vuejs2.

This way I'm doing a link to a route called "Client**S**"

```
<router-link :to="{name : 'clients'}">Link to CLIENTS</router-link>
```

and it gives:

`<a class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">... </a>`

However I want that when another route is called, let's say CLIENT (singular), the route 'client**s**' also gets the class router-link-active. How to do that ?

Comment: use a single route, there is no need to use singular/multiple routes for the same thing, though you could do `:class="{'router-link-exact-active router-link-active': $route.name === 'client'}"` or whatever the correct value for $route.name would be, though will get ugly quickly

Comment: you can also use an [alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias), but will get messy if you ever move to nuxt etc